# javascript exception when using foreach function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to parse an associated array returned from a PHP functoin like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../controllers/Checkpoint.php/getAllCheckpoints"
    }).done(function( result ) {
        result.foreach(function(index, value){
            alert(index + "  "+ value);
        });
    }).error(function(){

    });
```

i return the array like this **in php**

```
foreach($result as $row) {
            $checkpoints[$row['ID']] = $row['Name'];
        }
        return json_encode($checkpoints);
```

the result of that array reading from the chrome F12 console is

```
{"1":"check point 1","2":"check point 2"}
```

I got this error in the javascript code:

```
ReferenceError: forEach is not defined
```

could you help me please

Comment: Your code has `foreach` (lower `e`), but your error message has `forEach` (upper `E`). Which did you actually use?

Comment: by the way, `{"1":"check point 1","2":"check point 2"}` is not an array.

Comment: @SultanBaby It's not, and OP does call it that, but OP also called it an associative array, [which is correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). This is an unfortunate clashing of PHP and JS terminology (personally I hate the term associative array, since it confuses people with terms for objects and normal arrays).

Comment: AFAIK, 'associated' is different from 'associative'. But most importantly, OP's recount of the issue is inconsistent as you already noted - there's no way one would use `foreach` but then get a mention of `forEach` in the error message.

Comment: @SultanBaby Good catch, I read "associated" as "associative". That is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the jQuery.each() generic iterator function in combination with the javascript JSON.parse() to accomplish what you are attempting to do.

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
.done(function( result ) {
    checkpoints = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each( checkpoints, function( index, value) {
         alert(index + "  "+ value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### On client side

you should use `object.forEach()` function `e` capital letter or jQuery function `$.each(object)`

```
    result.forEach(function(index, value){
        alert(index + "  "+ value);
    });
```

If you have not set response header `Content-type: application/json` then you will need to parse response content as `JSON` object use `JSON.parse()` function

```
.done(function( result ) {

    JSON.parse(result).forEach(function(index, value){
        alert(index + "  "+ value);
    });
})
```

### On Server side

`return` mean function that `return` and assign value into any variable, `AJAX` response need output buffer so `echo` content on server side and terminate script after output buffer

```
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $checkpoints[$row['ID']] = $row['Name'];
    }
    //return json_encode($checkpoints);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($checkpoints);
    exit();
```

`header('Content-type: application/json');` means response content type as json object

Comment: For older browsers that don't have `JSON`, there's also [`jQuery.parseJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Comment: yes @ajp15243 may be required, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data on client, on browser then Php is no is problem ok.
When you is on client.
Javascript native isnt have function foreach, You can use $.each function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../controllers/Checkpoint.php/getAllCheckpoints"
}).done(function( result ) {
    $.each(result, function(i, data){
        console.log(i, data); // this print on console the data that you is run
        // for this you should have installed firebug on firefox or chrome already installed some similar.
    });
}).error(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first: You have to return the php result with "echo" and not with "return".